# Magento 2: Show a message on place order button click for a few seconds

Tags: magento2, checkout, place-order

I want to show a message on the checkout place order button click for a few seconds before the place order event. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. possible.
Need to override Place order js

> Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order).

> requirejs-config.js

```
    var config = {
        config: {
            mixins: {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                    'My_Module/js/action/place-order': true
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

> ```
> place-order.js
> ```

```
    define(['mage/utils/wrapper'], function (wrapper) {
        'use strict';
    
        return function (placeOrderAction) {
            return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, redirectOnSuccess) {
                // my own code here
                return originalAction(paymentData, redirectOnSuccess);
            });
        };
    });
```